# .htaccess 301 redirect only for Google bots

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, googlebot

What code do I need to add to .htaccess to redirect my old domain to the new one, but to do this not for users, but only for the **google bot**.
I have a variant of the code, but it doesn't work. It gives canonical to the old domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^googlebot
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What are the Googlebot user-agent strings?

Comment: To redirect only for google bot

Comment: That was a prompt / rhetorical question. [Here is the list of Googlebot user-agent strings](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/overview-google-crawlers) - from that list you can see that your regex `^googlebot` does not match any of the documented Googlebot user-agent strings so the rule is not going to do anything.

Comment: Although I would also have to ask _why_ you are wanting to do this? Strictly speaking, this is "cloaking" (serving one thing for search engines and another for users), which is against Google's T&Cs so this could incur a penalty.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this would be cloaking, I just want to try to put it into practice.